# How to turn on "windows behaviour" home/end keys on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

I'm a converted Mac user with a Windows past. I've been using a Mac laptop keyboard without home/end keys for several years now. Finally, I bought a Matias keyboard and found that home/end is different from what I got used to in Windows. In order to jump to the beginning/end of the line, I have to type `command` + `left` or `command` + `right`. How can I reassign this action to home/end keys? Thanks!

Comment: There is an answer in apple themed stackexchange site: [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/remap-home-and-end-to-beginning-and-end-of-line)